Problem with importing `catboost` package
I was trying to install catboost, and everything was going well until I decided to upgrade to Python 3.12. After the upgrade, I encountered an error when I tried to import it:
numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. 
Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

I attempted various approaches and even downgraded to a previous version, but the issue persisted. I then reverted to Python 3.11 and installed the package again, but I still encountered the same error. Additionally, I installed Numpy with the latest version.
I hope anyone helps because I feel like I'm selling the laptop soon.

Uninstalling Python 3.12 and reinstalling it with the 3.11 version, the problem persisted.
Uninstalling the packages and reinstalling it again, and also the error was still present.
I tried to run it in a conda environment with Python 3.12.4 and all things work fine.


Problem is with numpy 2.0
Currently, catboost does not support numpy 2.0: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/2671
You need to do:
pip install numpy==1.26.4

